# How can I name columns in a CSV output by pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am having some trouble writing a csv file that contains two columns. the first column contains intervals or bins while the second column contains a count of things in those bins. I made this csv file from another csv file containing raw data points. I am able to write the file but I am unable to name the columns. I expect that the output file should be a csv with two columns, so I supplied a list of two names to the .to_csv function and it comes up with this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/willi/Documents/Python/csv_processing_scratch/simple_csv_processor.py", line 65, in <module>
    create_binned_csv_counts(dir_stringx, data_bin_edges, "value_counts_x_frameintervalsize_" + str(frame_interval_size))
  File "C:/Users/willi/Documents/Python/csv_processing_scratch/simple_csv_processor.py", line 36, in create_binned_csv_counts
    pd.cut(data_array, bin_edges).value_counts().to_csv(vcfilestring,index_label=True, header=["Coordinate Bins", "Counts for time interval " + str(i)])
  File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4685, in to_csv
    return self.to_frame().to_csv(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3228, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 202, in save
    self._save()
  File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 310, in _save
    self._save_header()
  File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 239, in _save_header
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Writing 1 cols but got 2 aliases
```

The code block its coming from is this one

```
def create_binned_csv_counts(maindirectorystring, bin_edges, valuecountstring):
    i = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(maindirectorystring):
        vcfilestring = str(filename[0:18]) + "_value_counts.csv"
        os.chdir(maindirectorystring)
        os.chmod(filename, 0o7777)
        df = pd.read_csv(filename)
        data_array = df["Coordinates for bin " + str(i)].to_numpy()
        os.chdir(cwd)
        os.chdir(valuecountstring)
        pd.cut(data_array, bin_edges).value_counts().to_csv(vcfilestring,index_label=True, header=["Coordinate Bins", "Counts for time interval " + str(i)])
        os.chdir(cwd)
        i += 1
```

I was thinking it has something to do with the data types returned by cut and value_counts but searching through the documentation for those pandas methods wasnt very enlightening.

Let me know if I can provide more information, I appreciate any and all help I can get.

Also relevant, the first few lines of the output csv when I dont name the columns, I also am unsure of why that zero is there.

```
0
"(-10, -9]",0
"(-9, -8]",0
"(-8, -7]",0
"(-7, -6]",0
"(-6, -5]",0
"(-5, -4]",0
"(-4, -3]",0
"(-3, -2]",21
"(-2, -1]",13
"(-1, 0]",33
"(0, 1]",74
"(1, 2]",285
```

I would like it to look something like this

```
"Coordinate bins", "Count"
"(-10, -9]",0
"(-9, -8]",0
"(-8, -7]",0
"(-7, -6]",0
"(-6, -5]",0
"(-5, -4]",0
"(-4, -3]",0
"(-3, -2]",21
"(-2, -1]",13
"(-1, 0]",33
"(0, 1]",74
"(1, 2]",285
```

Comment: inside `to_csv` set `index=False`

Comment: Ah okay, that didnt exactly do it but it did get me to realize my confusion between index and index_label and their usages. Thank you, that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, YOLO helped me start thinking in the right direction, I changed the line with the to_csv file to this

```
pd.cut(data_array,bin_edges).value_counts().to_csv(vcfilestring,index_label="Coordinate Bins",index=True, header=["Counts for time interval " + str(i)])
```